# Limit writing of pandas to_excel to 1 million rows per sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame with around 28 millions rows (5 columns) and I'm struggling to write that to an excel, which is limited to 1,048,576 rows, I can't have that in more than one workbook so I'll need to split thoes 28Mi into 28 sheets and so on.

this is what I'm doing with it:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NAME_XX-' + mes +'-' + ano + '_XXX.xlsx', engine = "xlsxwriter")

notMor.to_excel(writer, engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)
```

and getting this error:
[image]

I tought of splitting the dataframe into 27 different ones and then saving each one on the workbook but there isn't a simpler way?

Comment: you could use `df.groupby(df.index//1000000)` to get 28 grouped sub dfs... but copying that much data, split into many sheets, is not good practice for excel.. you would be better off creating a binary file and connecting to it from excel, what will you do with the excel after you paste the data?

Comment: _I tought of splitting the dataframe into 27 different ones and then saving each one on the workbook but there isn't a simpler way?_ How tough would that be? A for loop should do the trick, right?

Comment: I need the data inside the one workbook without any link to another file. I know it'll be a huge xlsx file that'll take a forever to open but it's what i have to present. Guess I'll have to split the df, i was hoping for something like a parameter passed to the "to_excel" whereI could limit the number of rows and then keep creating and populating new sheets.

Comment: @LucasMarques Did you ever solve this? I have a very similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

- One option is to save the file to a `csv`, and use the Excel Data Model, which has a row limit of `1,999,999,997`, to import the file.

  - See [Data Model specification and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef).

1. In Excel 2016, and Excel for Microsoft 365, use **Data** > **Get & Transform Data** > **Get Data** to import data from any number of external data sources, such as a text file, Excel workbook, website, Microsoft Access, SQL Server, or another relational database that contains multiple related tables.

   - In Excel 2013 and 2010, go to **Power Query** > **Get External Data**, and select your data source.
2. Excel prompts you to select a table. If you want to get multiple tables from the same data source, check the **Enable selection of multiple tables** option. When you select multiple tables, Excel automatically creates a Data Model for you.
3. Select one or more tables, then click **Load**.

- [Create a Data Model in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-model-in-excel-87e7a54c-87dc-488e-9410-5c75dbcb0f7b#:%7E:text=A%20Data%20Model%20allows%20you,source%20inside%20an%20Excel%20workbook.&text=A%20Data%20Model%20is%20visualized,never%20even%20know%20it%27s%20there.)
- [Introduction to the Query Editor (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-the-query-editor-power-query-1d6cdb63-bf70-4ae8-a7d5-6ae9547004d9)

[image]

- This example has 3M rows

[image]

Comment: is there a way i could do that through code? I need to run this script and have the file ready without having to open the xlsx file.

Comment: @LucasMarques I guess it's not clear what you need Excel for. Regardless of the file format (csv or xlsx), it still needs to load if you're using Excel. Using the data model, you would have an Excel file (my.xlsx), and inside the file, you would configure the datamodel connection to the my.csv. When the Excel file is opened, it would have the connection to the csv, that you could refresh if there's new information. Also, the data model can connect to multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had implemented the following. It's my pleasure if this helps you at all.

```
rows_per_sheet = 100000
number_of_sheets = floor((len(data)/rows_per_sheet))+1
start_index=0
end_index = rows_per_sheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)
for i in range(number_of_sheets):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(data[start_index:end_index]), columns=columns)
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='sheet_'+str(i))
    start_index = end_index
    end_index = end_index + rows_per_sheet
    

writer.save()
```

However, to create multiple sheets on a same file would cost you a lot of time as every time it needs to load the original file which gets incremented every time. In this case you can create multiple excel file instead of multiple sheets-

```
rows_per_file = 1000000
number_of_files = floor((len(data)/rows_per_file))+1
start_index=0
end_index = rows_per_file
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=columns)
for i in range(number_of_files):
    filepart = 'file' + '_'+ str(i) + '.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepart)
    df_mod = df.iloc[start_index:end_index]
    df_mod.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='sheet')
    start_index = end_index
    end_index = end_index + rows_per_file
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

simply / easy / fast --> download your data to a CSV split by 1000000 from Pandas and then have Excel open it. Excel will adjust and open across multiple sheets accordingly.

Some code you can tweak:

```
#split file code
lines_per_file = 1000000
smallfile = None
with open('Plan.txt') as bigfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            if smallfile:
                smallfile.close()
            small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
            smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
        smallfile.write(line)
    if smallfile:
        smallfile.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's kinda like what I was saying about splitting the df and then saving each 1mi group on a different sheet but with your code I'm saving to a csv file.